# Utilizar no neo4j cláusulas WHERE condicionando se valor existe

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Boa tarde galera!

Estou com uma pequena dúvida e ainda não encontrei uma resposta elegante na documentação do neo4j.

Estou montando um endpoint com vários parâmetros de combinação para busca, então é possível que alguns dos parâmetros ou venha vazio ou nulo. Desta forma, gostaria de aplicar as cláusulas WHERE apenas quando houver valor no parâmetro.

Se alguém poder dar uma orientação de como fazer.

PS: Vi na documentação que de Expressions o "CASE", entretanto não sei se é viável colocar dentro do WHERE vários CASES concatenados.

Obrigado!! ;)

Comment: E que linguagem de programação você está usando para montar a query em si? Eu não sei neo4j, mas em SQL, em geral resolvo isso na montagem da query, construindo a string que a representa.
Independe disso, não quer adicionar à questão um exemplo da query, e talvez um pouco do código em volta que você ja tem aí?

Comment: Estou usando a seguinte query:

MATCH (n:Place)
WHERE (
 n.country = '' XOR
 n.state = '' XOR
 n.city = '' XOR
 n.latitude = 34.2651 XOR
 n.longitude = -77.867 XOR
 n.name =~ '.*.*' XOR 
 n.businessActivity =~ '' XOR
 n.businessSubActivity =~ ''
 ) 
RETURN n 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 20

Comment: Estou usando Cypher.